# Path/namespace collisions for identical C libraries

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile, shared-libraries

## Background

I'm working with a massive `C` library used to interface with our products. We initially had a single product, `coconut`, which utilized `libfruit.so`, along with all the associated API header files for `libfruit`. The header files themselves don't use relative path includes, but rather, project root includes. For example, consider these two actual headers:

```
${LIBFRUIT_BASE}/headers/Include/fruit/framework/beta/base.h
${LIBFRUIT_BASE}/headers/Include/fruit/framework/beta/coconut.h
```

In the `coconut.h` file, it includes `base.h` via:

```
#include "Include/fruit/framework/beta/base.h"
```

It does this by setting something like `CFLAGS+= -I ${LIBFRUIT_BASE}/headers`. External programs that build against `libfruit` similarly set a path flag to resolve the headers.

---

## Problem

This works when building `libfruit`, and when building a program that depends on `libfruit` easily enough, but now we have a big problem:

1. We want to support an additional product, `pineapple`.
2. The developers for `libfruit` decided to fork `libfruit` so that there is a different version for each product.

Handling two libraries was easy enough, as we now have a `libfruit_coconut.so` (renamed `libfruit.so`) and a `libfruit_pineapple.so`. After removing global exported symbols from both libraries with name collisions, the libraries were working. However, there's still one more big problem though: the publicly exported headers for both `libfruit_coconut` and `libfruit_pineapple` collide, i.e.:

**`libfruit_coconut`:**

```
~/projects/myapp/dependencies/headers/Include/fruit/framework/beta/base.h
~/projects/myapp/dependencies/headers/Include/fruit/framework/beta/coconut.h
```

**`libfruit_pineapple`:**

```
~/projects/myapp/dependencies/headers/Include/fruit/framework/beta/base.h
~/projects/myapp/dependencies/headers/Include/fruit/framework/beta/pineapple.h
```

This is where everything falls apart: I have to use two versions of a near identical library, and `base.h` is overwritten depending on which of the two dependencies I copy in first. The first step I did was to move each library into it's own distinct sub-directory in my build environment:

```
~/projects/myapp/dependencies/libfruit_coconut/headers/Include/fruit/framework/beta/base.h
~/projects/myapp/dependencies/libfruit_coconut/headers/Include/fruit/framework/beta/coconut.h
~/projects/myapp/dependencies/libfruit_pineapple/headers/Include/fruit/framework/beta/base.h
~/projects/myapp/dependencies/libfruit_pineapple/headers/Include/fruit/framework/beta/pineapple.h
```

This didn't completely resolve my problem though: the headers provided by both libraries don't use relative include paths, and the library headers complain about not being able to find other headers from the same library unless I set my include path for **both** sets of headers, i.e.:

```
CFLAGS += -I~/projects/myapp/dependencies/libfruit_coconut   \
          -I~/projects/myapp/dependencies/libfruit_pineapple
```

This seems to effectively make it impossible for the project to utilize both libraries at one without headers being resolved non-deterministically.

---

## Question

Assuming I can't change either of the `libfruit` libraries, their headers, etc; is there any sane way to somehow use both libraries at once in a single project? The center of my problem appears to be how the library headers themselves reference each other. Or am I stuck forcing the library developers to use relative include paths for their API headers, or inserting `libfruit_${VARIANT_NAME}` in all their headers?

Comment: One very useful method would be to require that each library submitted for use in the project request from the project lead, then  use unique short (eg. 3 character) prefix for all symbols for a particular library to be exported.  This nearly guarantees that there will be no collisions between libraries.  For example `coc_func1()` for coconut.  `pin_func1()` for pineapple.

Comment: *"Assuming I can't change either of the libfruit libraries, their headers, etc"* That seems like trouble when you need to add `libfruit_orange`. Why not have one base library, and add-on library for each indivudual fruit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you cannot change the existing libraries or headers, the only way to do what you are asking is to create a separate, new wrapper library for each existing library/header, and within each shared library project, *wrap* or *typedef* all of the existing symbols (that have the potential for conflict) with with unique prefix identifiers, such as `pin_` or `coc_` (for pineapple, coconut respectively).  Paths existing in the original headers can be replaced with symbolic links to original locations in the wrapper headers to alleviate the header problems.  This approach should eliminate all conflicts.  You can then build (and deliver) a single shared library that contains all of the functionality of the original collection of sub-libraries.

Using this approach, although admittedly brute force, and not ideal, provides a flexible way forward for feature expansion in an application (or library) being developed outside of some kind of overall design or project management.